# Why can't I fetch the JSONArray from the web

Tags: android

I want to fetch the JSONArray from the internet and show it in the logcat so I use
Log.e("result ", result);

But it seems fail because I can't find any of the JSONArraay in the logcat
Here's my code and I hope you can have a look and tell me what's wrong ?
I know some of you are using BufferReader to read the text from internet
but I guess my way should also be OK

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnParse;
    ListView listResult;

    btnParse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_parse);

    listResult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_result);

    btnParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONArray trial = getJSONData();

        }
    });

}

private JSONArray getJSONData() {

    String url = "http://cloud.culture.tw/frontsite/trans/SearchShowAction.do?method=doFindAllTypeJ";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);

        String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        Log.e("result ", result);

        JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(result);
        return jsonarr;

    } catch (Exception err) {
        return null;

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you remember to request the `INTERNET` permission in your application's manifest?

Comment: Print exceptions you get instead of dropping them, e.g. `Log.e("yourtag", "exeption while fetching", err);` before your `return null;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not allow networking on the UI thread. Therefore, when you call `HttpResponse httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);` It is throwing an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception. It would be more useful for you to call `Log.e("error",err.printStackTrace())`in the catch block rather than returning null as this error would be revealed in the logcat. You need to move the code int the try block to another thread. I recommend using an AsyncTask. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details on this. The basics about `AsyncTask`: it is a class that abstracts the use of a thread and a handler away from the developer. If you are familiar with threads and handlers you can implement your own solution (not an async task) to avoid having to conform to the asynctask frame work.

Comment: what if I write my own DefaultHttpClient like 

private DefaultHttpClient gethttpclient(){
}
and the I use the returnDefaultHttpClient.execute(httpget);

Can the problem be solved ?

Comment: Dose it mean that every time I want to connect to the internet in 
android I have to do it using AsyncTask.

Comment: @海志李 No, creating a separate method will not automagically move it to a new thread. That call would still be synchronous (blocking) and would cause the UI to hang. You need to use a handler or async task or some other method to generate another thread... Volley even... If you want a simple solution that is a bad idea, turn off strict mode...

Comment: @海志李 For the most part, yes. WebView won't require that because it handles threading on it's own, but outside of that you usually will... Check out Volley though, it's simpler than AsyncTask...

Comment: THZ a lot.

It is really helpful ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ever since Android 3.0, StrictMode has been enabled by default. What it does it prohibit developers from doing lazy things such as running network code on the UI thread. It forces you to run such code asynchronously so that the application doesn't hang/pause and user interaction remains uninterrupted. You can turn that off so that you don't need to use an AsyncTask/Handler/Volley/whatever. It's a bad way to handle it, but here's one way to do it (**don't do this**):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); // Put these two lines before you execute your HTTTP request....
```

**Do this instead:**
Use [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley), here's a [quick tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library). Also, [a Google Talk about it](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728).